# Looping the array in select

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this kind of array shown in Picture. How can i insert the values in the select option as

```
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="13000">13000</option>
<option value="19AAAAA">19AAAAA</option>
<option value="sdsdas">sdsdas</option>
<option value="dasdasdasd">dasdasdasd</option>
```

[image: Array Pic]

Comment: make a single array and then loop through it.

Comment: Single array is not the solution

Comment: Do you want to group them as in this 3D php array.. optgroup might be a solution. But you need to at-least reduce the php array to 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach($arr as $val){
   foreach($val as $val2){ 
       foreach($val2 as $val3){ ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $val3;?>"><?php echo $val3 ;?></option><?php
       }
   } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Your val2 == array

Answer (score 3):

Simply flatten the multi-dimensional array, and then loop through it.

*Suppose `$arr` in your original multi-dimensional array*

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($it as $value){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
    <?php
}
```

Here are the relevant references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: hi, sorry this comment was not ment for you, just moved it to another answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Auris No issues. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flat array. You can do it with recursive function. Here you have general function for that.

```
/**
 * Get multilevel array convert to single-level array
 * @param $array
 * @return array
 */
function getFlattened($array) {
    $flattened = [];
    foreach ($array as $flat) {
        if (is_array($flat)) {
            $flatArray = array_merge($flatArray, getFlattened($flat));
        } else {
            $flattened[] = $flat;
        }
    }

    return $flattened;
}
```

Of course you can use that approach to recursively display select - not only to flat array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($array as $inner): ?>
    <?php foreach($inner as $innerTwo): ?>
        <?php foreach($innerTwo as $item): ?>
            <option value="<?= $item ?>"><?= $item ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: no not the same the index may be [0] or may be upto 100

Comment: ok, updated to match multiple indexes on all levels. You are using this in only one place, this solution is fine, if you will need to reuse this functionality, lukdur's suggestion of recursive array flattening will work better

Answer (score 0):

you may try this.

```
<?php
$input = Array(
    Array
(
    0 => 7,
    1 => 13000
),
Array
(
    0 => '19AAAAA',
    1 => 'sdsdas'
)
    );


$options = "";
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $input);

for($i = 0;$i< count($result);$i++ ){


    $options .="<option value='".$result[$i]."'>".$result[$i]."</option>";


}

echo $options;
```